# Projectivity and idempotents

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring over field $k$, let us denote $A\otimes_k A$ by $A^e$. In Jacobson Basic Algebra II, Page 375, Exercise 6.11, it was asked to prove that if $A^e$ has an idempotent $x$ such that $(a\otimes1)x=(1\otimes a)x$ for all $a\in A$, then $A$ is $A^e$ projective.

For projectivity, it suffices to show that $A$ is a summand of $A^e$ as $A^e$-module.

We can always define the splitting $s$ to the augmentation map $\epsilon\colon A^e\to A, \sum a_i\otimes b_i\to \sum a_ib_i$ by $s(\epsilon(a))=ax$. The previous equalities ensure that $s$ is well defined. However it is unclear how to show $\epsilon s=1_A$.

Comment: Clearly the statement is not correct as written since you can always take $x=0$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes thanks, so what kind of condition might be imposed? Asking the element e to be non-trivial?

Comment: Probably the condition $\epsilon(x)=1$ was meant to be included.

Comment: P.S.  If you add that condition you get the standard definition of a "separability idempotent".

Comment: Thanks for the reference! @JeremyRickard